# Is it possible to change the value of an HTML button by passing URL parameters?

Tags: html, excel, vba

**The issue**
I am setting up an IQY query to access data with Excel from the web. This is normally pretty straightforward and done by just providing the URL to the data and then select what to download. But the the data I am interested in is located in a table that can switch between different time-spans by clicking an HTML button.

What I think I need to know is if I can manipulate HTML buttons using parameters passed in the URL. Lets say that I want to access "www.datasource.org/data".  At this page there is a table that can be altered by clicking a button with the following code:

```
<button class="ctt ctt_Text ctt-default" value="2" type="button">Button Text</button>
```

The default value of the button seem to be "1" (which is the table shown when visiting www.datasource.org/data), but can I change the value to 2 by passing a parameter in the URL instead of clicking the button that changes it? Or is there perhaps someone who can suggest a different solution?

Comment: Unless the owner of the site has linked the button value to a querystring parameter you will not be able to pass in the value via the URL.  It's likely you'd be able to automate IE to change the button value before clicking it.  Google "VBA automate IE" for examples of how to control IE from VBA.

Comment: Thank you. I think I will give up on this because VBA-IE seem a bit too complicated for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can get url by JavaScript:

```
window.location.href
```

Or PHP:

```
$_GET['Variable Name'];
```

Comment: I do not control the website. I am only a paying member of the site and trying to make better use of the information on it by automating my reading.